# Java Ajax Framework integration

Tags: java, javascript, ajax

I'm looking for a java AJAX framework which I can include into my existing webapp. I've found [sweetDev RIA](http://sweetdev-ria.ideotechnologies.com/sweetdev-ria-gettingStarted-3.3.5//) . Are there such other frameworks which I could look into it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last couple of years, I have been developing rich looking web applications with [icefaces](http://www.icefaces.org).  It is pretty cool, ajax is buit-in and it blends very well with jsf. If you use icefaces, javascript is not required anymore. In our web project we use javascript only in couple of places.

Here is an excerpt from icefaces homepage: "As a leading open source Ajax framework, ICEfaces is more than a Ajax JSF component library, it's an J2EE Ajax framework for developing and deploying rich enterprise applications (REAs). With ICEfaces, enterprise Java developers can easily develop rich enterprise applications in Java, not JavaScript."

Comment: Is it possible to use ICEfaces along with jboss portal server and using them in portlets?

Answer (score 1):

I'd take a look at [DWR](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/): Direct Web Remoting.  It allows you to directly call Java (web services) from JavaScript in a really intuitive way.

Answer (score 0):

I would really check out [extjs.com](http://extjs.com). It is the most feature complete javascript component library I know of. The components are fast, have beautiful default styling, and the API is very powerful. AJAX support is also excellent. Most of my current web development include extjs in some way.

It's very easy to use this library with java. Most of the time, I just have some server side component that returns data in JSON.

There is also [ExtTLD](http://www.exttld.com/); a tablib wrapper for extjs. I have never used it myself, though.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest ExtJS (with jQuery underneath), but you might prefer [GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/).  I think it's easier for Java programmers who are seeking to wade slowly into JavaScript waters.

Answer (score 0):

Google Web Toolkit ( [GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/) )

Answer (score 0):

you can also use Apache's 'Myfaces' project http://myfaces.apache.org
Its a JSF implementation, and also has components with in built ajax capability.

Answer (score 0):

You can try SweetDevRia, it's possible to add ajax in your application without writing Javascript. You only need to use JSP tags